# Loop through listbox rows if column is not empty copy paste to empty row in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I'm trying to loop through listbox(attached picture below), and if the column(3) has value, then copy & paste row to empty row in excel sheet for later use.
I wanted to copy the row using column value to put it in sheet, but it just copys last row value, and repeats.
Could you please point out what I did wrong in the below code?

TIA

```
s = 22

For i = 0 To Me.AnBox.ListCount - 1

    If Me.AnBox.Column(3) <> "" Then

        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("A" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.Column(2)
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("C" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.Column(1)
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("D" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.Column(3)
        s = s + 1

    End If

Next i
```

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjlce.png)

[Part of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmjoz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Few errors:

- The index of your `ListBox.Column` is zero based, so you not looking at the third but second `Index`.
- You are accessing the values wrongly, trying to read a full column so it seems. The correct syntax is `expression.Column(pvargColumn, pvargIndex)` so you are missing a parameter. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.listbox.column) remarks to see the difference between using the second parameter or not.
- Make use of the iteration and the more common [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.listbox.list) property to access each row individually.

So therefor your code could look like:

```
s = 22
For i = 0 To Me.AnBox.ListCount - 1
    If Me.AnBox.List(i, 2) <> "" Then
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("A" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.List(i, 1)
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("C" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.List(i, 0)
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("D" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.List(i, 2)
        s = s + 1 
    End If
Next i
```

It is possible through the `Column` property too though:

```
s = 22
For i = 0 To Me.AnBox.ListCount - 1
    If Me.AnBox.Column(2, i) <> "" Then
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("A" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.Column(1, i)
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("C" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.Column(0, i)
        Sheets("SparePartsRequestForm").Range("D" & s).Value = Me.AnBox.Column(2, i)
        s = s + 1 
    End If
Next i
```

<sub>**Note:** If your intention is to paste at the next available row, there are great ways to return the last used row of a range. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/9758194) for example</sub>